# Process Laravel/Redis job from multiple server

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, server-side, distributed-computing

We are building a reporting app on Laravel that need to fetch users data from a third-party server that allow 1 request per seconds.

We need to fetch **100K** to **1000K** rows based on user and we can fetch max 250 rows per request.

So the restriction is:

#### 1. We can send 1 request per seconds

#### 2. 250 rows per request

So, it requires 400-4000 request/jobs to fetch a user data, So, loading data for multiple users is very time-consuming and the server gets slow.

So, now, we are planning to load the data using multiple servers, like 4-10 servers to fetch users data, so we can send 10 requests per second from 10 servers.

How can we design the system and process jobs from multiple servers?

Is it possible to use a dedicated server for hosting Redis and connect to that Redis server from multiple servers and execute jobs? Can any conflict/race-condition happen?

Any hint or prior experience related to this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, this is absolutely possible and is something I've implemented in production apps many times before.

Redis is just like any other service and can run anywhere, with clients from anywhere, connecting to it. It's all up to your configuration of the server to dictate how exactly that happens (and adding passwords, configuring spiped, limiting access via the firewall, etc.). I'd reccommend reading up on the documentation they have in the Administration section here: https://redis.io/documentation

Also, when you do make the move to a dedicated Redis host, with multiple clients accessing it, you'll likely want to look into having more than just one Redis server running for reliability, high availability, etc. Redis has efficient and easy replication available with a few simple configuration commands, which you can read more about here: https://redis.io/topics/replication

Last thing on Redis, if you do end up implementing a master-slave set up, you may want to look into high availability and auto-failover if your Master instance were to go down. Redis has a really great utility built into the application that can monitor your Master and Slaves, detect when the Master is down, and automatically re-configure your servers to promote one of the slaves to the new master. The utility is called Redis Sentinel, and you can read about that here: https://redis.io/topics/sentinel

For your question about race conditions, it depends on how exactly you write your jobs that are pushed onto the queue. For your use case though, it doesn't sound like this would be too much of an issue, but it really depends on the constraints of the third-party system. Either way, if you are subject to a race condition, you can still implement a solution for it, but would likely need to use something like a Redis Lock (https://redis.io/topics/distlock). Taylor recently added a new feature to the upcoming Laravel version 5.6 that I believe implements a version of the Redis Lock in the scheduler (https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/laravel-5-6-preview-single-server-scheduling-54df8e0e139b). You can look into how that was implemented, and adapt for your use case if you end up needing it.